# Sort Date Time Strings in R Data Frame Column

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have a `Time` column in my data frame `df` that is of type character.

After using `Arrange()` in the `dplyr` package, my `Time` column is sorted as:

```
D1W12001
D1W12002
...
D1W22001
D1W22002
...
D2W12001
D2W12002
...
```

But I need it to sort chronologically as:

```
D1W12001
D2W12001
D3W12001
...
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? 
Can I just sort the string in opposite direction (from left to right instead)?
Or do I need to first convert my column to a datetime object? What is the best package to use for that?

**UPDATE:**

I guess I didnt ask the question very well. Let me clarify.

Lets assume the times are in random order and have the format DxWxYear, where D is day, W is week and Year is year.
There are 5 days in a week, 52 weeks in a year, and years 2001 to 2011.

These "times" are character strings.

So my un-ordered data might look like:

```
D4W72002
D2W32009
D5w372001
D2w152003
...
```

continues like that for many rows..

Now I need it chronologically such as:

```
D1W12001
D2W12001
D3W12001
D4W12001
D5W12001
D1W22001
D2W22001
...
D4W522011
D5W522011
```

Now how can I order my times?

Doing `order()` or `Arrange()` sorts them as strings and thus it is incrementing them from the right, so it looks like the following:

```
D1W12001
D1W12002
D1W12003
D1W12004
D1W12005
...
```

Thats is not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried `order`?  Also, there is a `sort.POSIXlt` method

Comment: `gtools::mixedsort` comes to mind

Comment: yes, `order` does the same thing since I am sorting a string, unless there is a method I should use that will start the sorting from the left.

Comment: Is it a string or a time format?

Comment: The Time column is currently a character string

Comment: Will this do the trick for you?  `df[order(substring(df$Time, 5, 8)), ]`

Comment: Or maybe `df[order(gsub(".*W", "", df$Time)), ]`

Comment: No, neither of those approaches work. Its still sorting right to left, starting with the year

Comment: My suggestion was intended to sort the data by the second four characters in the time variable, i.e., ignoring the `D#W#` and sorting by the `200#`.  Isn't that what you're trying to do?   Not sure what you mean by "sorting right to left, starting with the year".  Could you post the output from `dput(df[1:20, ])` or some subset of the data so we can test out our methods on it?

Comment: Ahh, I think I see now.  You want to ignore `D#W` and sort by `#200#`.  If that's the case, try `df[order(substring(df$Time, 4, 8)), ]`.

Comment: i dont want to ignore anything.. just sort chronologically

Comment: Right, but what characters in df$Time define the chronology you want to sort by?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a reverse function to change the order of the string so normal `sort()` function would work.

```
stringReverse <- function(x) {
  d <- substring(x$Time, 1, 2)
  w <- substring(x$Time, 3, 4)
  y <- substring(x$Time, 5, 8)
  return(paste(y,w,d,sep=""))
}
```

call that function replace the `Time` column in my `df`:

```
df$Time <- stringReplace(df)
```

Now I can use `arrange()` to sort as I please.

Can revert the `Time` string back to how it originally was after arranging with a different reverse function.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  However, your `substring` for week and year won't work when you have a mixture of one-digit and two-digit numbers for the week.  That's why I used `nchar` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a way to do this using a date format, but I didn't see one.  I tried using `strftime()` but it seems that the format for week of the year is expecting a leading zero.  I looked into using the `parse_date_time()` in the lubridate package, but there the format for the weekday is expecting values 0-6 rather than 1-7.

So, I used `substring()` and `strsplit()` instead, trimming off the year, then splitting the remainder in two.

```
nc <- nchar(df$Time)
year <- substring(df$Time, nc-3, nc)
dw <- strsplit(substring(df$Time, 2, nc-4), "W")
day <- as.numeric(sapply(dw, "[", 1))
week <- as.numeric(sapply(dw, "[", 2))
ord <- order(year, week, day)

df[ord, ]
```